# Vlookup: I have to search for the lookup_value in the table_array for the result to show

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm using VLOOKUP in Excel and have the formula working properly between two tabs of data. The problem is that I have about 3000 rows of data I'm trying to populate, but for the most part, the fields aren't populating *until* I do a search for the lookup_value in the table_array in the other tab.

For example, say my lookup_value in one case is '123' and I know for a fact that '123' exists in my table_array on the other tab. The result is #N/A until I use the *Search in Workbook* tool for '123' and sure enough, it finds it in the other tab next to the corresponding data I'm looking for. When I toggle back to the other tab, lo and behold, suddenly the correct value is listed where #N/A used to be.

This is literally the opposite of the supposed benefit of VLOOKUP. Has anyone else experienced this and found a solution? I've tried quitting Excel and reopening but no luck.

Comment: Is calculation set to automatic?

Comment: My guess is that it has to do with a data type mismatch. Maybe the value you are looking for is numeric, but the values in table_array are text -- and so the vlookup does not find any match. In some cases I have seen, selecting a cell with a number in text format causes it to be re-typed as a numeric. As soon as that happens the vlookup finds it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the formula set to 0 (or FALSE) for exact match?.

3000 rows of data is definitely not enough to slow down your processes. Also, you mentioned it's in two tabs and not any external links...so that's also not the issue.

Are you using an older version of Excel or a downloaded file that is in compatibility mode? If so, try to open a fresh workbook and copy/paste your data over into a new workbook. Then your formulas should work.